# iPhone - What is the control in the middle of the in call screen?

Tags: iphone, screen, call

As a small project to get myself used to some more iPhone elements I've decided to create a sample in call screen, modeling it on the native iPhone call screen (IOS 4)

However I'm struggling to make out what elements the native in call screen uses to make up the view that is displayed.

I was wondering if someone with more experience on iPhone could help me out by explaining what the various elements are?

Is the bottom part a UIActionSheet that is slightly transparent and with a UIBUtton placed over it? Or is it a slightly transparent imageview with the button over-layed?

Similarly at the top, it looks like its an imageiew with the name or number of the callee/caller and the call duration underneath, would I be correct in thinking that?

The part I'm really interested in is the bit where the icons are held in some sort of dialog in the centre of the screen that is animated to swing around to a keypad when it is selected, is this some sort of iPhone control that I can use or customise?

[image]

**EDIT:**

I've tried two things to try to achieve this so far:

1) I've created a view within a view and I am trying to flip this however I can only seem to get the main view to flip properly and not the view inside it which is the one I want and it doesn't seem to be a good approach.

2) I've tried to look at using the Utility application approach to it but again this seems to be for flipping the full screen and not just a section within a screen (view)

Has anybody got any pointers on what to try next? Or if one of the above methods is the ideal way to do it and should be investigated further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a basic level, I would say that the panel of 6 buttons is simply a view with 6 buttons laid out in it as subviews.

The rounded corners and border stroke can be achieved by accessing the view's layer property and the layer's properties for cornerRadius, borderWidth, and borderColor, e.g.

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
view.layer.borderWidth = 2;
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

This requires including the `CoreGraphics` Framework, and the appropriate header files in your code.

I notice there's a gradient (or it appears to be a gradient) in the border stroke. I am not sure how to achieve that without doing something more involved and clever (such as a containing view that is just slightly larger veritically and horizontally than the view containing the buttons and is filled with a gradient color. The result would be a gradient border, but this doesn't seem like the best way to do that...

The flip is actually pretty easy. You can create a UIView animation with something like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
        forView:view cache:NO]
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Does this help, or at least get you started?

Comment: It certainly has got me a lot further along the way :) I've hit one problem though, when I use that code to flip the view my entire view flips and I cant figure out how to just flip the view I have in the centre of the screen?

Comment: @Mark Granoff - What about Bottom Control ? That is UIButton or some other thing??

Comment: @Astanienohpi Yep, it's a button inside a rectangular view.

Comment: @Mark Granoff : how it's border with gap? any spl property i have to set or else some other control

Comment: @Astanienohpi It looks like it's a custom graphic, so you'd have to craft something like that yourself.